# I create a cmyk image by php imagemagick, but cmyk color is different on photoshop?

Tags: php, imagemagick, cmyk

NEED HELP!
I create a cmyk image by php imagemagick, but cmyk color is different on photoshop! e.g.: set ImagickPixel color cmyk(0,0,0,100)(black), but found cmyk(61,61,61,0) on photoshop.
why? and how to set the correct cmyk color?

Comment: here is my code: http://liudonghua.net/use-imagemagick-to-create-cmyk-image-in-php/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the colorspace to CMYK,  other wise your pixels will be converted to RGB.

```
$img->setImageColorspace(Imagick::COLORSPACE_CMYK);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.setimagecolorspace.php

Also all make sure that you are using file type that supports CMYK. ( eg. .jpg, .tif )

**Edit**

It seems Imagick has a bug.
Until it is fixed you can try and use this work around using `transformImageColorspace`.

```
$draw = new \ImagickDraw();

$fillColor = new \ImagickPixel();    
$fillColor->setColor('cmyk(0%,0%,0%,100%');
$draw->setFillColor($fillColor);
$draw->rectangle(100, 100, 400, 400);

$img = new \Imagick();
$img->newImage(500, 500, 'white');
$img->drawImage($draw);
$img->transformImageColorspace(Imagick::COLORSPACE_CMYK);
$img->setImageFormat("jpg");

header('Content-Type: image/'.$img->getImageFormat());
echo $img;
```

Comment: I have set colorspace and file type is .jpg, photoshop shows the image is as CMYK color modal.

Comment: Yes, the CMYK color space is invalid for ImagickDraw, except the bug fixed. Your solution works for me, but if more colors needed to printing, there's color problem.

Comment: @hcoat did you get this working? please see my question